Do we still need a closing tag on empty <script>?
For many years we have been writing
<script src="code.js"></script>

Is that still necessary or can we now write just
<script src="code.js" />


It is still necessary

@RoryMcCrossan In all web browsers? Is there anything new in the html standard?

Go nuts: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/scripting.html#the-script-element

See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28719226/519413
